# XSL-FOP text decoration extend line

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I'm still a newbiew when it comes to XML, XSL, FOP.

How can I obtain an output having a long line with a text underneath it? something like:

```
<fo:inline text-decoration> Signature </fo:inline>
```

The only problem on this is that the line is too small. I want the line to be longer.

I want to have 2 sets of this on the same line. One is `Signature` and the other is `Date`

Please help. :)

Comment: As written, this is not valid I think (attribute name `text-decoration` without a value). Please show a bit more around this place, the containing fo:block and fo:block-container and a valid xml code for the fo:inline with all attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple signature block like you are trying to create, just use a table like this:

```
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border-top="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>Signature</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block/>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border-top="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>Date</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
```

Which gives you this:

[image]